# Numbers no longer opens .xls spreadsheet

Tags: macbook-pro, numbers

I have very recently converted to a MacBook Air from a PC and have a 1.3mb .xls file which 1 week ago Numbers happily opened, edited and saved in its own format.

Today, when I opened it it was corrupted. So I have been trying to open the original .xls file again and the Numbers message is simply 'the file will not open'. No explanation, no clues as to why.

I can still open another (very much smaller and simpler) .xls file but don't know what to do next...

Comment: I would try to restore the original file from a TimeMachine backup if you have one.  If not this would be a good time to set up a TimeMachine backup, very very easy to do with a Mac and OS X.  I would also try opening the original xls file in [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) or [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) both of which are free.

Comment: What happens if you try opening the file by dragging it to a web browser with iWork for iCloud? That might rule out if the problem is numbers on your computer or if the file has been damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say both files have somehow become corrupted and Numbers cannot recover from the errors.

I would try to restore the original file from a TimeMachine backup if you have one. If not this would be a good time to set up a TimeMachine backup, very very easy to do with a Mac and OS X.

I would also try opening the original xls file in [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) or [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) both of which are free.

Comment: Thanks. Apache Open Office works just great, and seems a better spreadsheet app than Numbers too

Comment: There is no doubt that OpenSource tools have come a long way and are excellent.

Answer (score 0):

My imperfect solution was to open up the XLS file in an old version of Numbers and then copy and pasted it into the current version. Total PITA but works.